# Create an upper triangular matrix/table to collect correlation coefficients from user in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am working on creating an upper triangular matrix to let the user input the correlation coefficients between correlated dependent variables (e.g., different traits). I was able to achieve this using r package `shinyMatrix` (see screenshot). However, this package only supports the whole matrix rather than the upper-triangular matrix. I temporarily put a `NA` in the lower-triangular part, but the user can still delete the `NA` and enter any number here. I thought about using `numericInput`, but can not figure out the solution as the dimension and column/row names of the input matrix are reactive (depends on user & it looks not as nice as matrix input). My question is how to create an reactive upper triangular matrix (e.g., block the `click` of lower-triangle elements using `Javascript`)? If this is not applicable, is it possible to fix all lower triangular elements as "NA" (can not be changed by user) using `shinyMatrix`? Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated!

**Below is a small example code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- basicPage(
  fluidRow(column(6,
           numericInput("ntrait", "Number of traits", value = 1,
                        min = 1))),
  fluidRow(column(6, style='padding:0px;', 
                  wellPanel(uiOutput("TPhenocor"))))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$TPhenocor <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$ntrait)
    dmat <- diag(num)
    dmat[lower.tri(dmat)] <- NA
    switch(num>1,
           matrixInput(
             inputId = "ycor",
             label = "Correlation coefficients matrix",
             value = dmat,
             class = "character",
             cols = list(names = FALSE), 
             rows = list(names = FALSE)), NULL)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**Update:** I was able to create the upper triangle matrix and also restrict changing in diagonal and lower triangle just using R code (see below). I can share a demo if anyone needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to `observe` the `shinyMatrix` input and enforce the symmetry. That is, overwriting the lower triangular matrix with the values from the upper triangular matrix whenever we are not symmetric. This does not prevent the user from entering values there, but  will overwrite them as soon as he/she tries.

Add this observer to your server:

```r
observeEvent(input$ycor, {
   mat <- input$ycor
   req(!isSymmetric(mat)) 
   ## fires only if we are not symmetrical otherwise we would end up in an infinite loop
   mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- mat[upper.tri(mat)]
   updateMatrixInput(session, "ycor", mat)
})
```

Another solution would be to use `Javascript` to remove all `click` events from the lower triangular matrix. In this way the user cannot enter values there.

You can use the following `jQuery`, which disables the 3rd cell (in row order), it is left to you to adapt the code such that all lower triangular elements are selected:

```
$('.matrix-input-cell').eq(2).off('click')
```

You can try this code when you run your app and issue this command directly in the JavaScript console. In Chrome you reach the console via

> Right Click -> Inspect -> Console

You will see that you cannot click (and thus modify) the 3rd cell in row order [assuming of course there is a 3rd cell].

To run this from Shiny you want to add a `script` element, for instance in your UI:

```r
tags$head(tags$script(type="text/javascript", "$(function() {$('.matrix-input-cell').eq(2).off('click')}"))
```

the `$(function()` bit is `jQuery` code, which runs the callback function as soon as the DOM is loaded.

With your current approach this may be trickier, because your `shinyMatrix` element is not rendered when the DOM is loaded as it is dynamic. So you will need to trigger the `JavaScript` code in your `observer`. `library(shinyjs)` will be your friend.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I am more interested in "remove" all `click` events using `Javascript`. I am new to `Javascript`, can you share a small demo or point me to some associated reading? @thothal

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I was able to create a upper triangle matrix only use R code.